# using submit(), but also need to set the submit button

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I'm using the jquery submit() function. However this is not compatible with my code, as the url does not add the submit button as a variable `search_btn`. So in the url it is not displayed there, which means my variables are not set due to:

```
if(isset($_GET['search_btn'])) {
   // set variables
}
```

the jquery code changes the form fields and then submits the form:

```
$('#search_form').submit();
```

I tried also to click the button with jquery

```
$('#search_btn').trigger();
```

AND

```
$('#search_btn').click();
```

But they didn't do anything. How is this achieved?

Comment: **$('#search_btn').trigger();** is wrong.  Add the event:  **$('#search_btn').trigger("click");**

Comment: still didnt submit the form

Comment: Your "submit button" obviously isn't an actual input element.  Make it one (or add a hidden field) and it will get passed.

Comment: oops! sorry I was using the name not the id, it worked, thats great thanks!